# How to place 'cards' over the page in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4, overlay

I have an .ejs/.html page setup using Bootstrap 4.  It is a standard 'sign-in' page that displays a form in the middle of the interface.  It is taken from a UI template freely available on the Internet, a synopsis as follows:

```
<body>

<h1 class="heads">Sign-In</h1>

 <div class="container" style="z-index: 1;">
  <div class="page-header header-filter" style="background-image: url('../assets/img/bg7.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: top center;">

   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 ml-auto mr-auto">
      <div class="card card-login">

       <form class="was-validated" action="/form_handle" method="post">

       //inputs for credentials

       </form>

      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
  //stuff
  </footer>

 </div>
```

I am attempting to place some 'cards' that should display 'over' the page display.  They are to be in a column form along the 'left' side of the interface.  I am able to place the cards, however for some reason they are not evenly spaced on the vertical.  In addition my 'form' that had previously been centered instead becomes 'crunched' as if the 'cards' are affecting it.  Here is the code with the three 'cards' added:

```
    <body>

    <h1 class="heads">Sign-In</h1>

     <div class="container" style="z-index: 1;">
      <div class="page-header header-filter" style="background-image: url('../assets/img/bg7.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: top center;">

<div class="column">
<div class="w-50"> 
    <div class="card" style="z-index: 2; height: auto;">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Regular header</h4>
        <p class="category">Category subtitle</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        The place is close to Barceloneta Beach and bus stop just 2 min by walk and near to "Naviglio" where you can enjoy the main night life in Barcelona...
      </div>
    </div>

</br>

    <div class="card" style="z-index: 2; height: auto;">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Regular header</h4>
        <p class="category">Category subtitle</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        The place is close to Barceloneta Beach and bus stop just 2 min by walk and near to "Naviglio" where you can enjoy the main night life in Barcelona...
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" style="z-index: 2; height: auto;">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Regular header</h4>
        <p class="category">Category subtitle</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        The place is close to Barceloneta Beach and bus stop just 2 min by walk and near to "Naviglio" where you can enjoy the main night life in Barcelona...
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

       <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 ml-auto mr-auto">
          <div class="card card-login">

           <form class="was-validated" action="/form_handle" method="post">

           //inputs for credentials

           </form>

          </div>
         </div>

        </div>
       </div>

      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
      //stuff
      </footer>

     </div>

   </body>
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to properly accomplish this.  As can be seen in the code, I thought the way to accomplish this is by using the 'z-axis'...?
The only other way I can think of is to place each 'card' with 'absolute' positioning, for example 'card 1' 10% from the 'left side', 25% from the 'top'...'card 2' 10% from the 'left side', 50% from the 'top'...'card 3' 10% from the 'left side', 75% from the 'top'.  However I am not sure if absolute positioning is possible in Bootstrap due to the grid system...?  I thank thank you in advance.  Regards.